# Stop jQuery.transition

Tags: jquery

[This library](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) creates some nice smooth transitions, but sometimes I need to stop an animation an early. Typically, I'd do that with `.stop(true)`, but that method doesn't seem to work with `jQuery.transition`. Is there another way?

---

Edit: I might be crazy. It *does* seem to be working now.

Answer (score 2):

Try: http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/

```
  var myDiv = $("div");
  myDiv.clearQueue();
```

> In this way it is similar to .stop(true). However, while the .stop() method is meant to be used only with animations, .clearQueue() can also be used to remove any function that has been added to a generic jQuery queue with the .queue() method.

Comment: This doesn't stop the current transition